# Remove class if id's the correct ID

Tags: javascript

Looking to remove a class if a certain button is clicked.

```
<div class="slide-container">
    <section class="about" id="slide-0">
      <div class="menu-total">
        <nav class="nav">
          <button class="nav_link home" onclick="slideTo('slide-2')">HOME</button>
          <button class="nav_link about" onclick="slideTo('slide-0')">ABOUT</button>
          <button class="nav_link fun-stuff" onclick="slideTo('slide-1')">FUN STUFF</button>
          <button class="nav_link professional" onclick="slideTo('slide-3')">PROFESSIONAL</button>
          <button class="nav_link contact" onclick="slideTo('slide-4')">CONTACT</button>
        </nav>

      <div class="hamburger">
        <span class="hamburger__patty"></span>
        <span class="hamburger__patty"></span>
        <span class="hamburger__patty"></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

The one I want to remove the class on is the HOME button. So "slideTo('slide-2)". If it's clicked on the others then the class is kept. I believe someone is either wrong with my loop or not getting the ID correctly of the items/

```
function slideTo(slideId) {
    const slide = document.getElementById(slideId);
    slide.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    })


// above this line works fine

    let nonHome = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-container section');
    let nonHomeID = document.getElementById('slide-2');


    var i;
    setTimeout(function(){
      for (i=0; i < nonHome.length; i++ ){

// i believe it's somewhere here it is wrong

        if (nonHome[i].id != nonHomeID){
          nonHome[i].classList.add("nav-visibility");
        } else{
          nonHomeID.classList.remove("nav-visibility");
        }

      }
    }, 1000)


  }
```

Comment: First off, your function `slideTo` uses `getElementById`, and you're calling it with `slideTo('slide-2')`, which is fine, except that your buttons do not have any `id` on them. Second, why are you using a `setTimeout` to hide your buttons? You need them to hide one by one after a a second?

Comment: The setTimeout is to mainly add the class to the non 'slide-2' ones so its a delay on adding the class. Was thinking about doing the same soft opacity to 0 when removing the class which was the idea.

Comment: Don't know if it solves the issue, but the `<section>` tag is not closed. A `</section>` is required before the last `</div>` in the HTML part.

Comment: Appreciate that @vicraj but just didnt have it on there to not show the whole page code

Comment: @MPortman OK, thanks for the clarification. Like @FF suggested, an ID is required for each button: `<button id="button_home" class="nav_link home" ...>`, etc., otherwise `nonHome[i].id` will always return `undefined`.

Comment: Oops totally overlooked that they weren't IDs but actually the functions. If I didn't want to put IDs to keep it cleaner any advice on how to check if its onclick="slideTo('slide-2')" or not? @vicraj or FF?

Comment: Also on load it adds IDs. I believe thats due to the top lines of the function...?

Comment: @MPortman I answered you in a separate answer using `jquery`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `jquery` library, you can write in the HTML:

```
 <button class="nav_link" data-value="home">HOME</button>
 ...
```

and then in the JS code:

```
$(".nav_link").on("click", function() {
    var valueClicked = $(this).data("value"); // Get the data-value clicked

    $(".nav_link").each(function() { // Loop through all elements of the class 'nav-link'
       var v = $(this).data("value");
       if (v == valueClicked) {
           $(this).removeClass("nav-visibility"); 
       } else {
           $(this).addClass("nav-visibility"); 
       }
    )
}
```

Not much simpler, but the HTML is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't var v's "value" be "home"?

Comment: Or is it just that if the home button has any value and the others dont?

Comment: Yes, you're right, to fit your requirement it should be set to "home".

Comment: Is this the right setup?

```$(".nav_link").on("click", function() {
  var valueClicked = $(this).data("home"); // Get the data-value clicked

  $(".nav_link").each(function() { // Loop through all elements of the class 'nav-link'
     var v = $(this).data("home");
     if (v == valueClicked) {
         $(this).removeClass("nav-visibility"); 
         console.log('remove')
     } else {
         $(this).addClass("nav-visibility"); 
         console.log('add')
     }
    })

})
```

  <button class="nav_link home" data-value="home" onclick="slideTo('slide-2')">HOME</button>

Comment: If you only need to change the class of the value clicked (and not brose through all buttons using `each`), then it can be simpler. I'll wrote it in a separate answer for sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler version if it is not required to browse through all buttons at each button click:

```
$(".nav_link").on("click", function() {
    var valueClicked = $(this).data("value"); // The value of the button clicked by the user

    if (valueClicked == "home") {
        $(this).removeClass("nav-visibility");
        console.log('remove')
    } else { $(this).addClass("nav-visibility");
        console.log('add')
    }
});
```